# Application of the Park transform, matrix derivative without an input vector

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

MathJax wont produce a matrix for me so I have to post pictures:

I am trying to perform a Park transform on a three phase balanced inverter. Every paper I come across does not explain the transformation from $abc$ to $dq0$. I have found an explanation but it also says ["All identities may be proved by straightforward algebraic operations."](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/8/9/1661) I cant see how this works:

if

[image]

and its inverse is

[image]

Then how is it possible that:

[image]

I tried to take the time derivative of $T^{-1}_{\theta}$ with $\theta = \omega*t$ element wise but that didn't work. Every resource I came come across on Matrix differentiation relies on an input vector.

Does anyone have a link to a resource that could help me come up with the bottom result.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{T}}{\partial \theta}
=
-\frac23
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin \theta
&
\sin 
(\theta-2\pi/3)
& 
\sin
(\theta+2\pi/3) \\
\cos \theta &
\cos 
(\theta-2\pi/3) &
\cos 
(\theta+2\pi/3) \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we immediately observe that
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{T}}{\partial \theta}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{T}
=
\mathbf{UT}
$$

Taking differentials give
\begin{eqnarray*}
d \mathbf{T}
&=&
\frac{\partial \mathbf{T}}{\partial \theta}
d\theta  =
\frac{\partial \mathbf{T}}{\partial \theta}
\dot{\theta} dt =
\dot{\theta}\mathbf{UT}
dt=
\mathbf{WT}
dt
\end{eqnarray*}
with
$$
\mathbf{W}
=\dot{\theta}\mathbf{U}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \dot{\theta} & 0 \\
-\dot{\theta} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This indicates that
$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{T}}{\partial t}
=
\mathbf{WT}
$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
d \mathbf{T}^{-1}
&=&- \mathbf{T}^{-1} 
(d\mathbf{T}) \mathbf{T}^{-1} \\
&=&- \mathbf{T}^{-1} \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{T}}{\partial \theta}\right) \mathbf{T}^{-1}
d\theta = 
- \mathbf{T}^{-1} \mathbf{U}d\theta \\
&=&
- \mathbf{T}^{-1} 
\mathbf{U} \dot{\theta} dt
=
-\mathbf{T}^{-1} \mathbf{W} dt
\end{eqnarray*}
This indicates that
$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{T}^{-1}}{\partial t}
=
-\mathbf{T}^{-1} \mathbf{W}
$.

Answer (score 0):

The element-wise differentiation was the good path. Indeed, one has :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} T_\theta^{-1} = -\dot{\theta}
   \begin{pmatrix}
      \sin(\theta)        & \cos(\theta)        & 0 \\
      \sin(\theta-2\pi/3) & \cos(\theta-2\pi/3) & 0 \\
      \sin(\theta+2\pi/3) & \cos(\theta+2\pi/3) & 0 
   \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\dot{\theta} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}$. You can verify by a mere matrix multplication that the above expression is indeed equal to $-T_\theta W$. And it goes the same way for $\frac{\mathrm{d}T_\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why my brain doesn't like these...